# Is it possible to change the width of a div inside of a media query in CSS?

Tags: css, text

I Have a div that looks just fine on a regular desktop. However, When it's a laptop or smaller size it's going to need some adjusting. [image: div]This is what it looks like on a desktop. My goal is to widen the text. What I want to do is have each segment separate for smaller devices. The text is so narrow you are only reading two or three words per line and that could be annoying to a reader.

Here is the HTML code:

```
  <div id="work" class="full-width">
            <div class="third-width">
                <img src="../img/icon-html.png" alt="HTML icon" />
                <h3>Hand-Coded HTML</h3>
                <p>My focus is writing clean, well formatted, semantic HTML5 by hand to make sure that the content is easy
                    to read, easy to collaborate, trouble-shoot and accessible.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="third-width">
                <img src="../img/icon-css.png" alt="CSS icon" />
                <h3>Well-Organized CSS</h3>
                <p>I pride myself on writing CSS that is easy to read and build on. I focus on keeping my CSS lean and fast
                    to load, and I make it a habit to stay up to date on current best practices.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="code" class="third-width">
                <img src="../img/icon-pencil.png" alt="Pencil icon" />
                <h3>Ease Converting Designs into Code</h3>
                <p>You can trust me to take a designer's PSD and quickly &amp; accurately convert it into a webpage that
                    is pixel-perfect match.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
```

and this is the CSS I am trying to manipulate:

```
 .third-width .fullwidth {
    display:block; 
    float: none; 



}
```

For now, when I manage to center it the text is very narrow, maybe two or three words together. What I want to do is make a media query for the third-width class. This is the media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 786px) and (max-width: 1100px) {

.third-width .fullwidth {
    display:block; 
    float: none; 



} }
```

How would you widen the div so that the text looks a little more normal? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely possible. However, in order for us to help you with CSS, you will need to provide both your CSS and your HTML; we can't reproduce your problem without it. Please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. It would also help to specify any frameworks in play. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Bootstrap grid system will help you

Comment: Your CSS code still doesn't create a verifiable example, nor does it include any media queries. Please post **all relevant code** to reproduce the issue illustrated by your screenshot.

Comment: Is this clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS code was wrong, so that couldn't work. I think I believe what you are trying to accomplish and it would be best done using a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

I kept the padding intact, but you may want to consider a different setting for [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) to allow for the browser to calculate spacing.

```css
.full-width {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  justify-content: center; /* Horizontal alignment */
  align-items: center; /* Vertical alignment */
}

.full-width .third-width {
  padding: 100px;
  width: calc( 100% / 3 );
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 786px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .full-width .third-width {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="work" class="full-width">
  <div class="third-width">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="HTML icon" />
    <h3>Hand-Coded HTML</h3>
    <p>My focus is writing clean, well formatted, semantic HTML5 by hand to make sure that the content is easy to read, easy to collaborate, trouble-shoot and accessible.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="third-width">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="CSS icon" />
    <h3>Well-Organized CSS</h3>
    <p>I pride myself on writing CSS that is easy to read and build on. I focus on keeping my CSS lean and fast to load, and I make it a habit to stay up to date on current best practices.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="code" class="third-width">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Pencil icon" />
    <h3>Ease Converting Designs into Code</h3>
    <p>You can trust me to take a designer's PSD and quickly &amp; accurately convert it into a webpage that is pixel-perfect match.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this https://jsfiddle.net/xstb5p0r/3/

```
.third-width{float:left;width:33.33%;padding:0px 5%;text-align:center;}
.full-width{display:flex;width:100%;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .full-width {
    display:block;
  }
  .third-width{width:100%;float:none;}
}
```